# Need help to query nested array on mongo

Tags: mongodb, sub-array

I am having following document structure in mongo db

```
{
"_id": {
    "name": "XYX",
    "rol_no": "1",
    "last_update_dt": "2021-05-10",
    
},
"stud_history": [{
    'std': 'xyz',
    'age': '16'
},
{
    'std': 'mnl',
    'age': '15'
}]
}
```

and i want to query data like

```
name:xyz, rol_no:1, last_update_dt: 2021-05-10 and age:16
```

here i have mentioned only 1 student but i need to query similarly for multiple students.

So my output will be

```
"_id": {
    "name": "XYX",
    "rol_no": "1",
    "last_update_dt": "2021-05-10",

},
'stud_history': {
    'std': 'xyz',
    'age': '16'
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `$elemMatch` operator inside the projection parameter of the match command to filter output that matches a certain condition.

```
db.collection.find({  // Find Query
  "_id.name": "XYX",
  "_id.rol_no": "1",
  "_id.last_update_dt": "2021-05-10",
},
{  // Projection Parameter
  "_id": 1,
  "stud_history": {
    "$elemMatch": {  // Filters array elements to those matching the provided condition
      "age": "16"
    }
  }
})
```

If you want to achieve the same using Aggregation, use the below query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id.name": "XYX",
      "_id.rol_no": "1",
      "_id.last_update_dt": "2021-05-10",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "stud_history": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$stud_history",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [ "$$item.age", "16" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // If you want the result to be an object instead of an array
    "$unwind": "$stud_history"
  },
])
```

Comment: can you post with aggregation?

Comment: Add aggregation example to the answer